# Do Full MVNO's need S-GW in their LTE network?

Tags: routing, wireless, firewall, switching, mobile

Presently I am analysing the LTE network architecture for a full MVNO network.

I am just wondering whether S-GW is required as part of MVNO LTE architecture or MNO - SGW will be able to communicate via S5/S8 interface with the MVNO P-GW ?
If S-GW needed then MNO-MME should communicate with MVNO-SGW and call should process with MVNO-PGW. Could anybody can clarify?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, S-GW is not required as part of full MVNO LTE architecture.

Because, in principle, the S-GW needs to connect to all the LTE Radio Network Coverage (eNodeB) and unfortunately, generally, a MVNO does not have such LTE Radio Network, that's why he is a MVNO.

But if the full MVNO want to have a S-GW anyway, he can, but he will need to connect to all the LTE eNodeB(all LTE coverage) of the hosting operator....

So, commonly, the radio coverage is managed by the hosting Operator, and the S-GW with also.

Your full MVNO **can** manage:

- HSS and/or P-GW

But the hosting operator should manage:

- **S-GW (connected to all the LTE eNodeB)**
- eNodeB
- MME (connected to all the eNodeB also)

**Conclusion:** Because S-GW needs to be connected to all the eNodeB of the hosting operator, it is preferred to keep S-GW to the hosting operator, not to the MVNO.

Comment: this reads like you're pasting a post from somewhere else